# Agregar excepcion Try y Catch

Tags: java

Cree un programa que solicite una frase por teclado y muestre en pantalla la posición del carácter que tiene un valor ASCII mayor. El programa debe validar que la frase escrita por el usuario no tenga alguno de los siguientes símbolos: $, & o #. En caso de presentarse alguno de dichos símbolos el programa debe mostrar un mensaje de error y terminar su ejecución

Es el programa a elaborar y tengo esto realizado:

```
package errores2;

public class ascii {
  String cadena;
  private int i;

  public void splitcadena(){

    try{
      for(int i=0;i<cadena.length();i++){
        int as=cadena.charAt(i);
      }
    } catch(Exception a){
      // catch error a
    }
  }
}

package errores2;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner read=new Scanner(System.in);
      ascii q=new ascii();
      System.out.println("Digite frase a convertir");
      q.cadena=read.nextLine();
      q.splitcadena();
    }
}
```

Comment: es una condición que debes utilizar un try y catch, no veo que sea un requerimiento puede hacerse sin eso, y cual es tu pregunta en si, que necesitas? como tienes el código solo faltaría preguntar si as es alguno de los caracteres especiales y lanzar la excepción con throw new Exception(). pero como dije no creo que sea necesario usar una excepción en esta ocasión.

Answer (score 2):

Para ver si la cadena contiene alguno de esos caracteres yo utilizaría la siguiente expresión regular:
`".*[$&#].*"`.
Esa expresión regular quiere decir lo siguiente. El punto representa cualquier carácter, el asterisco representa 0 o N veces, y los caracteres entre corchetes representan  una posición, por lo tanto esa expresión regular es positiva si contiene `$` o `&` o `#`.

```
    String regExp=".*[hxx].*";
    if(cadena.matches(regExp)){
        System.out.println("Mensaje de error");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

O tal vez usaría un metodo dentro de tu clase ascii tipo: 
     q.salirSiContiene("$");

```
 public void salirSiContiene(String caracter){ 
    if(cadena.contains(caracter)){
        System.out.println("La cadena contiene "+caracter);
        System.exit(0);
    } 
 }
```

Para localizar el carácter mayor si la cadena no ha sido descartada, yo haría lo siguiente:

```
    char mayor = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i++) {
        if ((int) cadena.charAt(i) > mayor) {
            mayor =  cadena.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println (mayor);
```

No necesitas el try catch.

Answer (score 1):

Lo solucioné con un ciclo

```
If(la casilla del arreglo era igual a tal caracter){
  throw new Exception();
```

Answer (score 0):

Has probado la función indexof()?

[Revisala aquí](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_indexof.htm)

Comment: Hola @OmarMurcia. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias ´por contribuir! ¿Podrías explicar con un poco más de detalle, mostrando cómo solucionaría la pregunta? La idea es aportar respuestas completas de calidad que sean útiles incluso para futuros lectores. Un enlace externo puede servir para complementar, pero el contenido principal debería estar en la respuesta. Quizás te interese realizar el [tour] y leer [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo filtrar primero que no contenga los símbolos: $, & o # con la función Contains() [Java.lang.String](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_contains.htm) en una condición `if(){}` en donde solicitas la palabra.

El orden sería:

- Solicitar la palabra en la función
- Verificar con un `if(){}` si contiene los simbolos que mencionas ($, &, #)
- Si es true la condición, envía el mensaje de error. Caso contrario recorre la palabra completa con el ciclo for buscando la posición del ascii más grande.

** Para obtener el ascii de una letra puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
Character.toString ((char) i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno, lo que he hecho es hacer el ejercicio con la ayuda de los métodos de [idelcano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/18493/idelcano) y una estrutura completa sería:

```
public class LetraMayor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Escribe una frase...");
        String miCadena = scn.nextLine();

        if (contieneCaracteresNoPermitidos(miCadena)) {
            System.err.println("La frase contiene: $, & o #.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("La letra mayor es: '" + letraMayor(miCadena) + "'");
        }
        scn.close();
    }

    public static boolean contieneCaracteresNoPermitidos(String cadena) {
        String regExp=".*[$&#].*";
        if(cadena.matches(regExp)){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static char letraMayor(String cadena) {
        int letraMayor = 0;// El valor mas bajo.

        for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i++) {
            int letraActual = (int) cadena.charAt(i);
            if (letraActual > letraMayor) {
                letraMayor = cadena.charAt(i);
            }
        }

        return (char) letraMayor;
    }
}
```

Es solo una estructura completa, pero la respuesta ya la tienes de [idelcano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/18493/idelcano), y como puedes ver en el código, no se usa ningún try/catch.